# Prevent TinyMCE prompting onbeforeunload with save from custom button

Tags: tinymce

I couldn't find any post regarding this issue, so this was my last way out. I'd like to somehow tell TinyMCE that I've taken care of the saving process (reset the isdirty I guess), but to keep checking for further changes without reloading the page. Ofcourse, if I do a location.reload it works, but that takes a bit of elegance out of it.

I have a custom save-button with the following method:

```
$("#saveAbout").click(function(){

tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
$("#outerWrapper").animate({opacity:0.3});
$("#bigloader").fadeIn();

var currentData = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
var currentLanguage = $("#currentLang").val();

$.post("src/actions/pup_about.php", { text: currentData, lang: currentLanguage })
.done(function(data) {
$("#bigloader").fadeOut();
$("#outerWrapper").animate({opacity:1});

// What to do here? 

});

});
```

This basically gets the contents and saves it through a PHP file. A neat ajax loader shows up and fades out during the process. The #outerWrapper div is a div around the TinyMCE in order to fade it slightly out during the save process.

Is there any smart way to tell TinyMCE that saving is done, but to keep looking for further changes?

Answer (score 0):

You could issue in your function

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').save();
```

this should then take care of setting everything else.